# How do you find the Laurent series expansion for the following function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I know this must be a momentously dumb question, but I have to ask.  How does one find the Laurent series expansion for $f(z) = \frac{1}{2z}$ for $0 < |z| < 1$?

I know that if $|z| < 1$ we have the following: $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$.  However, in my denominator I just have $z$ as opposed to $1-z$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{2z}=\frac{1/2}{z}$ is already in laurent expansion form about $0$,  $\frac{1}{2z}=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n z^n$, the only non zero $a_n$ being $a_{-1}=\frac{1}{2}$